# Winform repaint at 5 seconds

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have a OnPaint function that draws a chart:

```
 protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        cs.ChartArea = this.ClientRectangle;
        AddData();
        SetPlotArea(g);
        cs.AddChartStyle(g);
        dc.AddLines(g, cs);
        //lg.AddLegend(g, dc, cs);
        g.Dispose();
    }
```

I added a timer inside Form1() that should redraw the chart at every 5 seconds:

```
var timer = new Timer();
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
timer.Interval = 5000;
timer.Start();
```

and the time_Tick function:

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Repaint the chart
    }
```

It is possible to redraw the chart at every 5 seconds using timer_Tick function?

Comment: put `this.Invalidate();` in the tick code.  It's not clear where you are creating that timer, but it looks like that could leak memory — better to declare `private timer = new Timer();` in the form's scope.

Comment: Don't dispose of that Graphic object either, you didn't create it.

Comment: I'm adding the timer in the Form1() method. If you know a better place please let me know.

Comment: Move it above the Form() constructor line, so it becomes part of the form's scope.

Comment: Wait...why does the timer need to be in the form's scope? You don't need that for redrawing, unless you're planning on stopping the timer at some point. Considering his situation, he won't. So just a call to `Invalidate();` inside the tick method would do. No need to change the scope of the timer

Comment: I've used this.Invalidate() as you suggested and it works great. Please mark this as an answer. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.invalidate();
}
```